# Current though an impedance

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electrons

I've solved the problem using different method, Nodal, superposition, mesh..
I'm having a hard time trying to understand the real world application of what it mean to have negative current running though an impedance. Like for R1, it has a negative value, what does that mean in real world application?

thanks,[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what does that mean in real world application?

It means that if you connect your ammeter in the same direction as your chosen reference direction for the current through R1, you will read a negative value.

If you then swap the leads around, you will read a positive value. Both readings give you the same information; the magnitude and the direction of the current through R1.

Comment: tested it out with multisim software. If its negative than your reference direction is wrong and the real current is flowing the other direction and I did nodal to verify the results and at first i get zero. I had to swap out my higher potential (now lower) to get the correct current direction. I love this site!!!! thanks!!